# can you create a c++ file from an .o object file with makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

What I'm trying to do is create a c++ file from an object file but I cannot figure out a way to do so.

```
INCLUDEDIR = ../headers
CXXFLAGS   = -std=c++11 -I $(INCLUDEDIR) -Wall -Wfatal-errors -O2

all:primeFactors.o 

primeFactors.o: primeFactors.cpp $(INCLUDEDIR)/primeFactors.h
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

When I try to build this I get

> `make: *** No rule to make target 'primeFactors.cpp', needed by
>   'primeFactors.o'.  Stop.`

which I understand but when I take out the primeFactor.cpp argument I then get told there is nothing to be done with the make file. So is there a way to do this?

Comment: why do you think that it is possible at all?

Comment: There's a whole network dedicated to this https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ . It's not as easy as just compiling the object file and magically getting a cpp file out of it.

Comment: That's called a [disassembler](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers). and I'm willing to wager that's not what you want to do, unless you want to steal propriety code.

Comment: To answer the title of your question:  Yes, provided you have `Make` execute the tool that converts `.o` to `.cpp`.  Fundamentally, `Make` executes programs based on dependency rules.  The big issue is trying to find the program the converts `.o` to `.cpp`.

Comment: This looks more like a misunderstanding of the `make` message.  @Peter doesn't have `primeFactors.o`, but he also (probably) doesn't have `primeFactors.cpp`.  I'd bet he called his C++ file something else, or stored it somewhere else that `make` can't find.  @Peter, if you have written a program that you now want to compile and run, you have a completely different problem than what your question suggests.

Comment: @DaveM. Bingo. Wish I could could upvote that comment more than once.

Comment: @DaveM. I have `primeFactors.o` but I don't have `primeFactors.cpp` I can compile and run cpp files with make but as @GillBates says it is possible to build a cpp file, it's just not easy

Comment: @GillBates Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: @kabanus I am getting into looking at video game source code

Comment: [There are better ways](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/30775/tetrogl-an-opengl-game-tutorial-in-cplusplus-for-w). Google openGL/directx game tutorials to get started on your first game or just see code.

Answer (score 0):

In general; no, you cannot do that. An object file (.o file) is the result of the code passing through the compiler front-end (to parse the language) the optimizer (to make it run fast) and the compiler back-end (to produce code that will run on your CPU).
This process is *not* reversible. You cannot go from compiled code back to source.

Answer (score 0):

> can you create a c++ file from an .o object file with makefile?

A `makefile` will allow you to do that only if you have an underlying tool to do it. `make`, which uses makefiles to do its job, does not have any built-in mechanisms to pull that off.

Your `makefile` has a rule for building `primeFactors.o`.

```
primeFactors.o: primeFactors.cpp $(INCLUDEDIR)/primeFactors.h
```

It says that `primeFactors.cpp` and `$(INCLUDEDIR)/primeFactors.h` are needed to build `primeFactors.o`. If you don't have those files, or no rules to build them, there is no way for `make` to build `primeFactors.o`.

Comment: I don't think I created the makefile correctly, I wanted to build `primeFactors.cpp` not `primeFactors.o` . How would I use makefile to execute this?

Comment: @Peter, usually .cpp files are created by a user using a text editor. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Essentially to reverse engineer `primeFactors.o` into a cpp file but it seems more complicated than I initially thought

Comment: @Peter, `make` cannot generate a .o file from a .cpp files without a compiler. Similarly, it cannot generate a .cpp files from a .o files unless there is a program to do that. Unfortunately, there is no such program.